# Add a field to the Django admin for a custom user model

Tags: django

I have a custom user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_happy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm referencing it within `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

And I've generated an admin for it based on the UserAdmin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin

from .models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    pass
```

But the `is_happy` field doesn't appear in the user admin page.

How/where do I tell this UserAdmin about additional fields that I'd like it to display?

Further details

- Django v3.1.3
- Python v3.8.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin

from .models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = DjangoUserAdmin.fieldsets+ (
        (                      
            'Some heading', # you can also use None 
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_happy',
                ),
            },
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I think you can go about this.

But before that, I hope you have run the `python manage.py makemigrations` as well as `python manage.py migrate` so a s to reflects the changes in your database.

Then, you could simply make your admin.py file to be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

Or you could customize like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from .models import *

# Register your models here.

class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('is_happy',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'is_happy', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```